# This keyword and Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, this

I'm looping through an array, listening for a click.
Once a click is detected all classes are removed then ones added using this.

I've moved the this keyword around, thats about all I can think to do.

```
//vars for the buttons of the top carousel

const tCBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.featureNav li');

//add listener for options choice

for(i = 0; i < tCBtn.length; i++){
    tCBtn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {

        for(o = 0; o < tCBtn.length; o++) {
        tCBtn[o].classList.remove('carousel--active');

            this.classList.add('carousel--active');

        }
    })
}
```

All the array items have the class removed without issue, I'd then expect the class to be added to the array item that was clicked using "this" but it keeps saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at HTMLLIElement.
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem arrises due to the use of arrow functions. These do not have their own `this`.

You could try replacing the arrow function with a normal function, because normal functions do have their own `this`. It is also better if you add the `carousel--active` class after the loop is done.

```
for(let i = 0; i < tCBtn.length; i++){ 
   tCBtn[i].addEventListener('click', 
      function() {
         for(let o = 0; o < tCBtn.length; o++) {
            tCBtn[o].classList.remove('carousel--active');
         }
         this.classList.add('carousel--active');
      }
   );
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: You should look at the formattiing of that code - you've got a missing bracket.

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for the heads up. I improved the formatting a bit and added an MDN link. Couldn't find a missing bracket though.